# How to preselect first image swatch on Product detail page Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2.4

I want to preselect first available option for my configurable product on Magento 2(2.2.4) website.

Note: I am not a developer so when you answer plz reply with file path as well, I know i am asking so much but its really urgent and needed.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the file `swatch-renderer.js` from

> \vendor\magento\module-swatches\view\frontend\web\js

and put it in your theme folder like this:

> app\design\frontend[THEME][THEME NAME]\Magento_Swatches\web\js\

and add few lines of code under the init function of this function line no. around 285

```
$.widget('mage.SwatchRenderer', {
```

so, the new init function should look like this. Note the custom code is inside the comment (custom script to select swatches automatically).

```
     /**
     * @private
     */
    _init: function () {
        if (_.isEmpty(this.options.jsonConfig.images)) {
            this.options.useAjax = true;
            // creates debounced variant of _LoadProductMedia()
            // to use it in events handlers instead of _LoadProductMedia()
            this._debouncedLoadProductMedia = _.debounce(this._LoadProductMedia.bind(this), 500);
        }

        if (this.options.jsonConfig !== '' && this.options.jsonSwatchConfig !== '') {
            // store unsorted attributes
            this.options.jsonConfig.mappedAttributes = _.clone(this.options.jsonConfig.attributes);
            this._sortAttributes();
            this._RenderControls();

            //custom script to select swatches automatically
            if($('body').hasClass('catalog-product-view')){                 
                if (this.options.jsonConfig.attributes.length > 0) {
                    var selectswatch = this.element.find('.' + this.options.classes.attributeClass + ' .' + this.options.classes.attributeOptionsWrapper);
                    $.each(selectswatch, function (index, item) {
                        var swatchOption = $(item).find('div.swatch-option').first();
                        if (swatchOption.length && !$(item).find('div.swatch-option').hasClass('selected')) {
                            swatchOption.trigger('click');
                        }
                    });
                }
                var $selectedId = $('.color div.swatch-attribute-options').find('.selected').attr('id');
                localStorage.setItem("selectedId", $selectedId);
            }
            // end of custom script
            this._setPreSelectedGallery();
            $(this.element).trigger('swatch.initialized');
        } else {
            console.log('SwatchRenderer: No input data received');
        }
        this.options.tierPriceTemplate = $(this.options.tierPriceTemplateSelector).html();
    }
```

It's working for me. Please try this and let me know if it works for you. Sorry for the late reply. I am seeing this query now only.

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for answering but it didn't worked for me infact after doing this my swatches has disappeared.

Comment: @SumitSharma can you please share your swatch-renderer.js file? You have to do static content deploy after this change. I hope you did it.

Comment: @Gideon - it doesn't work at all: 1st picture is not changing -- 2nd if you have more than one swatches  is just selecting and trigger click on first one.

Comment: @Gideon I have tried it again and it worked but not the way i was expecting, when i go to product detail page, i see the first option is select but images are not loading for the selected option. Can you please check at your end let me know.